# Sum $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^2}{4^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am an Economics undergraduate who was reading through a textbook on statistical theory.

On one of the questions, I had to find the Variance of $X$ the joint probability distribution,

$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4^{x+y}}$, where $x$ and $y$ were discrete random variables $x=0,1,2,...$ and $y=0,1,2,...$

When calculating $Var(x)$, and trying to find $E(x^2)$ I got stuck at the summation for $\frac{X^2}{4^X}$ for $0\le X$.

Previously in the part when I calculated $E(x)$, I was able to sum $\frac{X}{4^X}$ using an AGP.

However, when looking at the variance portion, I'm not sure what kind of series this is, and what method I can use to derive an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you sure that's a joint probability distribution? I get $f(0,0)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want the value of

$$S := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^2}{4^k}$$

Let us start with the geometric series, with $x \in (-1,1)$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Take the derivative of this on both sides, multiply by $x$, then do both again. (The derivative of the sum can be taken term-by-term since the series converges absolutely.) You'll get that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 x^k = \frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}$$

This can be applied to your case if you notice that

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 \left( \frac 1 4 \right)^k$$

i.e. use $x=1/4$.

Comment: hmm, so I see that you used the basic geometric series and did differentiation to get the answer, may I know how you thought of this? what I can think of is because the original series goes from ( 0 + 1 + (\frac{1}{4}$)  + (\frac{4}{16}$) + (\frac{9}{64}$)  + ... ) so I noticed that there is a difference in the numerator from +1,+3,+5,+7, thus the common difference in the differences is +2... is that why I need to get the second derivative and manipulate to get a solution? Thanks !!

Comment: It's just something I know from experience. I see $\sum k^2 x^k$, which immediately is similar to the geometric series $\sum x^k$. I think how I might transform the latter into the former; taking the derivative would get me $\sum kx^{k-1}$. That's nice but I have to multiply by $x$ to get closer to the desired form, and I have to do the same again to get the exact same form.